Can we delete the [x11-unix] tag?
The x11-unix tag seems to have been accidentally created by the user who asked this question org.gnu.emacs - bwrap: Can't mount tmpfs on /newroot/tmp/.X11-unix: No such file or directory.
I don't think the tag will serve any purpose. Can we delete it?

The tag will automatically get erased when there's no items on it.  I don't think there's anything that we need to do except keep it unused
